python :fixe width column export excel
The following code generates an excel file. The width of the column is 8. I would like to fix it to 20 in my python code.
data = {'Nom \n du collaborateur': ['Jude Bellingham']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
file_path = "/home/jovyan/workspaces/syne_ctl_prm/output/OUTPUT_EXCEL_FILE.xlsx"
file_path
df.to_excel(file_path, index = False)`


You can adjust the width of the table by simply adjusting the width in the options settings as described in the documentation. Search for display.max_colwidth in the documentation.
### Test data
df = DataFrame({'text': ['foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo', 'bar bar bar bar bar'],
             'number': [1, 2]})

df.style.set_properties(subset=['text'], **{'width': '300px'})


salam ,thanks but I tried , it does not work. i mean the result in excel is the same , the width of my column is still the same

effectively with the command style.set_properties width, the column larger but after exporting excel and open it into excel the column is not larger

this code below works   # Chargement d'un classeur Excel existant
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path + file_name1)
Activation d'une feuille par son nom
worksheet = workbook['Instructions']
Définition de la largeur des colonnes
worksheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20
worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 50
workbook.save(file_path + file_name1)  but he column name is Age and if I try this worksheet.column_dimensions['Age'].width = 20. it does 'nt work any more

If this works, add it as a complete reply with the code well formatted instead of comment, it might help others in the future.
